# res.download not setting correct headers only in one express route

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, header, response

I have a main express route that once navigated to, should prompt a download of the specified file in res.download:

```
app.get('/download/:fileid', (req, res) => {
    var connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host     : 'localhost',
        user     : 'root',
        password : '',
        database : 'filesystem'
      });

    connection.connect(() => {
        console.log("Connection to database established");

    });
    connection.query(`SELECT * from files where fileid = '${req.params.fileid}'`, (error, results, fields) => {
        if (error) throw error;
        else if(results.length === 0){
            console.log("empty");
        }
        else{
            res.download(`./uploads/PFSk5x7bg.png`, 'PFSk5x7bg.png', (err) => {
                console.log(err);
            })
        }
    });

    connection.end();
})
```

However, when accessed, it simply displays the image on the webpage, and when I check the response headers, the content disposition header is missing. I have tried manually setting it with res.setheader, but still does not work.

I tried making another route just for testing:

```
app.get('/test', (req, res) => {
    res.download(`./uploads/PFSk5x7bg.png`, 'PFSk5x7bg.png', (err) => {
        console.log(err);
    })
})
```

and it works.... the content disposition header is there, the browser actually downloads the file.

Is anyone able to understand what I am doing wrong with my /download route?

***UPDATE:
I changed the name of the /download/:fileid route to /test/:fileid and it worked. I then changed it BACK to /download/:fileid and it now works...
does anyone have any idea what could of caused this?

Answer (score 1):

You have a few errors there, which can screw your debugging.

1. You have misplaced your `connection.end()` statement which will be called *immediately* after `connection.query()`. You should move it inside of `connection.query`'s callback.
2. Using relative paths instead of abolute ones. Try changing `'./uploads/PFSk5x7bg.png'` to `__dirname + '/uploads/PFSk5x7bg.png'`
3. Not using `res.end()` in the request where necessary may confuse browser's representation of response of your software.

   ```
   if (error) { 
       res.end();
       throw error;
   }else if(results.length === 0){
       res.end();
       console.log("empty");
   }
   else{
       res.download(`./uploads/PFSk5x7bg.png`, 'PFSk5x7bg.png', (err) => {
           console.log(err);
       })
   }
   ```